# morphism from adic spaces to schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry

Let $X:=Spa A$ be an affinoid adic space, and $\underline X $ the ringed space of $X$. Let $Y:=Spec B$ be an affine scheme, $f: \underline X \longrightarrow Y$ a morphism of ringed spaces.

How to define a morphism of rings $g: B \longrightarrow A$ such that $f$ is induced by $g$?

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious morphism between rings of global sections?

Comment: @Jérôme Poineau: the global section of $SpaA$ is $\hat A$, so there is $B \longrightarrow \hat A$.

Comment: Then I am not sure that it is possible to find such a morphism. How would you find $\hat{A} \to A$ that induces $\mathrm{Spa}A \simeq \mathrm{Spa}\hat{A} \to \mathrm{Spec}\hat{A}$? 